# Automatically creating AV exceptions

Tags: windows, winapi, antivirus

I've written a program that, when updates are available, will download an EXE file. Different antivirus programs on the end-users computers are obviously going to react to this download differently - for instance, Avast will just kill the download without asking if permission is granted, unless an exception is setup beforehand, or an option is ticked in settings (which i can't guarantee will be).

Is there any way to add an exception to all possible AV variants, without having to learn how to do it for each possible AV?

To add a rule to Windows firewall, the following line will suffice:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Blah blah" dir=in action=allow program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Yadda\yadda.exe" enable=yes
```

but i can't find a similar command for AV. I'm not against asking my endusers which AV product they use and writing something for each, but i'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Hmya, if you would write an anti-virus program, would you make it easy for a virus to add a rule?

Comment: @Hans not easy, no. I guess I was hoping for something like UAC - "this prog has tried to add an exception, will you allow it?".

Answer (score 0):

> Different antivirus programs on the end-users computers are obviously going to react to this download differently

Only if you are performing the download in a suspicious manner.  Web browsers and other data-downloading clients don't all have AV exceptions, do they?  No.  Neither should your app, if you are doing things the right way.  We live in a connected world. Downloading by itself is inherently safe.  It is *executing* downloaded code that may be risky.

> for instance, Avast will just kill the download without asking if permission is granted, unless an exception is setup beforehand, or an option is ticked in settings (which i can't guarantee will be).

IMHO, Avast is being stupid and over-paranoid if it is really doing that.

> Is there any way to add an exception to all possible AV variants, without having to learn how to do it for each possible AV?

No.  And that is assuming that AVs even allow rules to be set dynamically in the first place, which is not likely (otherwise, what is to stop a virus from setting a rule?)  Rules are user-defined, so AVs only allow rules to be set by human interaction.

> To add a rule to Windows firewall, the following line will suffice:
>
> ```
> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Blah blah" dir=in action=allow program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Yadda\yadda.exe" enable=yes
> ```

Firewalls are not the same as AVs.  And FYI, Windows Firewall has its own [public API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa36631.aspx) for letting apps set rules and port policies, if the user has permission to make changes to the policies. You do not need to resort to `netsh`.

> i can't find a similar command for AV.

Of course not.  That would be a huge security risk.

> I'm not against asking my endusers which AV product they use and writing something for each, but i'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

You should be able to avoid having to create any exceptions at all.  If your app needs an exception in an AV, chances are you are doing something wrong to being with.